# How to create a "DELETE" link in play2?

Tags: rest, playframework-2.0, http-delete

Play2 supports restful url, we can define in "routes" file:

```
DELETE   /users/:id   controllers.Users.delete(id)
```

But how do I create such a link in template? Is there a helper method to use, or do I have to add a special parameter in the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DELETE is not supported by HTML yet. There is a [proposal](http://amundsen.com/examples/put-delete-forms/) so it's supported in HTML 5, but it's not implemented anywhere.

So, no, you can't trigger that from a template directly. Jquery Ajax allows you to use PUT or DELETE, but that is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not very clear about "Jquery Ajax allows you to use PUT or DELETE, but that is not supported by all browsers". I thought it is just jquery send something like "PUT" or "DELETE" to the server side, why it need the support of browsers?

Comment: Some browsers can't use Ajax to do a PUT/DELETE request. In the end, jquery is only a wrapper over browser javascript, so that's the limiting factor. JQuery solves most of the issues, but some it can't :)

Comment: Hope someday I will encounter this problem to see what exactly it is, or never